# Transmission of a JPEG image to Email Address or Mobile Device

Tags: email, arduino, jpeg

Can anyone provide insight on how to send a JPEG image from an SD card on an Arduino Mega 2560 board to someone's email address or phone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have email that supports SMTP.

Use ethernet (or wifi) shield to connect your board to the internet.

THe following tutorial might help you how to configure SMTP from within your Arduino:
http://www.jayconsystems.com/tutorial/Ethernet_Send_Mail/

Comment: Does the same go for a wifi shield?

Comment: Yep - should not make any difference